# what is the Best Flutter version to install that has the most compatible plugins and what channel to stay on dev or stable

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I'm new to flutter  developing android and ios apps and there are just way too many flutter versions .

Are you able to advise me of the below as i am finding alot of plugins incompatible and am having to switch between versions:

```
flutter version v1.10.7
```

What is the best flutter version to install that has the most compatible plugins ?
And what is the best channel to stay on  dev or stable  ?

```
flutter channel dev
```

Thanks for the help as i cannot find any advise on the internet for the above 2 questions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be developing software in a good, stable environment, where all your packages are up to date and all the bugs are ironed out, use the `Stable` channel:

```
flutter channel stable
```

To quote the flutter [documentation](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Flutter-build-release-channels):

> Roughly once a quarter, a branch that has been stabilized on beta will become our next stable branch and we will create a stable release from that branch. **We recommend that you use this channel for all production app releases.**

Comment: whats the version of flutter that you are using .. your response does not really answer any question that i have posed , I have asked what is the Best and most compatible version for a developer to use  and what is the BEST   channel to use for a Developer.  The  documentation contain's recommendation it does not advise whats the BEST channel  or whats the BEST  version . stay on context !

Comment: I'm using the master version, because I don't develop an app that needs to be released productively anytime soon. If my answer does not answer your question, I suggest you clarify your question, because I don't understand it. There is no *best* channel, otherwise there would not be channels at all. Each channel is for a specific purpose and the channel best suited to the purpose *you* stated (plugins and packages working) is the **Stable** channel.